# Autoscaling libraries for Microsoft Azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure, enterprise-library

I want to implement an autoscaling block for web roles in microsoft azure and I found out that there are  many ways to do it. 
I found out, that Microsoft Enterprise Library has an Autoscaling Block that can be used for autoscaling. And in addition I found Microsoft Azure Monitoring Service Library which can manage autoscaling in Microsoft Azure too. 
I am somewhat confused now and I don't know which library is better and which advantages and disadvantages has each of both libraries. Unfortunately I have not found any compare of this libraries in Google.

Comment: Autoscaling application block (AKA WASABi) was released first.  Later, many of the features of the block were incorporated directly into azure.  Native azure should be the first choice.  If it can't do what you want then I would look for other options.  You can read a comparison (from 2013) in (Windows Azure autoscaling now built-in)[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/agile/archive/2013/07/02/windows-azure-autoscaling-now-built-in.aspx].

Comment: What do you mean with "native azure"? Autoscaling in management portal? Your link is corrupted :(

Comment: Yes, as part of the built-in, out of the box, Azure functionality (which is shown in the management portal) in contrast with a separate library requiring separate hosting, and configuration. I mean you should use the built-in functionality first (or at least consider it as a first option) before moving on to other approaches.